# Excel 365 copies cells as image

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

I just started to see a weird thing in Excel 365. I want to just copy-and-paste some cells, (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>) but it pastes them as an image, instead of cells with their content.

Is there some setting I might have inadvertently set? I tried looking online for solutions, but all I found is how to paste as image, not how to **not** paste as an image.

**Update** when trying with LibreOffice, it works fine.

**Update** I can see it goes wrong when copying, as there is a little delay as soon as I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>. So apparently Excel copies it as image.

**Update** when showing the clipboard from within Excel, I see it copies it two times when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, both plain and as image.

Comment: I didn't reproduce the issue in my Excel for Office 365. According to [Keyboard shortcuts in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-in-excel-1798d9d5-842a-42b8-9c99-9b7213f0040f), Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V are the right shortcuts to copy and paste. What/Where 's the content you use Ctrl+C to copy? Does the issue occur with new blank workbooks? Please try to check your clipboard after using Ctrl+C. In addition, please use other keyboards instead to have a check. As far as I know, you can select a destination and press Enter to paste after using Ctrl+C to copy cells in Excel.

Comment: I also happens on blank workbooks. How can I inspect the clipboard?

Comment: To open clipboard in Excel, see[Use the Office Clipboard](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/copy-and-paste-using-the-office-clipboard-714a72af-1ad4-450f-8708-c2931e73ec8a). Check if the content is a picture in clipboard after you use Ctrl+C to copy some cells/data. In addition, you can try to [open Excel in safe mode](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/open-office-apps-in-safe-mode-on-a-windows-pc-dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72), then create a blank workbook to check for the issue.

Comment: @HerbGu when looking at the clipboard, I see it makes two items when I do Ctrl-C. One normal one, and one image. Because the image is at the top, that one is pasted. Safe mode has the same behaviour.

Comment: It is weird. You can try to log in your computer with other or new accounts and open Excel under a different profile to check if the issue still occurs.